# No cipher suites in common in Jetty 9 SSL Configuration

Tags: java, jetty, jetty-9

I have spent the better part of the day on this and so far have been unable to get Jetty 9 configured to serve over HTTPS correctly. This is only for development purposes so I have generated a keystore file that I am attempting to use with Jetty.

I am generating the certificate like this:

```
keytool -keystore keystore -alias jetty -genkey -keyalg RSA
```

This is from the Jetty instructions at https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html.

Output from `mvn -X jetty:run` when I start the server showing the cipher suites:

```
[DEBUG] STARTED @7821ms org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector$ServerConnectorManager@677b8e13
[DEBUG] starting SslConnectionFactory@4158debd{SSL->http/1.1}
[DEBUG] run org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector@1b8d20e6 id=3 keys=0 selected=0
[DEBUG] EPR Idle/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@3519e9bc execute
[DEBUG] EPR Prod/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@3519e9bc produce enter
[DEBUG] EPR Prod/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@3519e9bc producing
[DEBUG] Selector loop waiting on select
[DEBUG] starting SslContextFactory@af78c87(null,null)
[DEBUG] Selected Protocols [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2] of [SSLv2Hello, SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
[DEBUG] Selected Ciphers   [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV] of [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV, TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_NULL_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5, TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5, TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5]
```

Output from `mvn -X jetty:run` from when I attempt to make a request to https://localhost:8443:

```
[DEBUG] Selector loop woken up from select, 0/0 selected
[DEBUG] EPR Prod/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@5235a7a1 produced org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$2@7ed55f41
[DEBUG] EPR Pend/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@5235a7a1 dispatch
[DEBUG] queue EPR Pend/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@5235a7a1
[DEBUG] EPR Pend/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@5235a7a1 run org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$2@7ed55f41
[DEBUG] run EPR Pend/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@5235a7a1
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1431)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:535)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:813)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.fill(SslConnection.java:509)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.fillRequestBuffer(HttpConnection.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1666)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:304)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:292)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.chooseCipherSuite(ServerHandshaker.java:1014)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientHello(ServerHandshaker.java:731)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:213)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:919)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:916)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1369)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.fill(SslConnection.java:613)
    ... 13 more
```

Here is the relevant section from my `pom.xml`:

```
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.3.6.v20151106</version>
    <configuration>                       
        <jettyXml>src/main/resources/jetty.xml,src/main/resources/jetty-
            ssl.xml,src/main/resources/jetty-https.xml,src/main/resources/jetty-ssl-context.xml</jettyXml>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
...
```

Here is my `jetty.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">

<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

    <New id="httpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
        <Set name="secureScheme">https</Set>
        <Set name="securePort"><Property name="jetty.secure.port" default="8443" /></Set>
        <Set name="outputBufferSize">32768</Set>
        <Set name="requestHeaderSize">8192</Set>
        <Set name="responseHeaderSize">8192</Set>
        <Set name="sendServerVersion">true</Set>
        <Set name="sendDateHeader">false</Set>
        <Set name="headerCacheSize">512</Set>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

`jetty-ssl.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">

<!-- ============================================================= -->
<!-- Base SSL configuration                                        -->
<!-- This configuration needs to be used together with 1 or more   -->
<!-- of jetty-https.xml or jetty-http2.xml                         -->
<!-- ============================================================= -->
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- Add a SSL Connector with no protocol factories              -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <Call  name="addConnector">
        <Arg>
            <New id="sslConnector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
                <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
                <Arg name="acceptors" type="int"><Property name="jetty.ssl.acceptors" deprecated="ssl.acceptors" default="-1"/></Arg>
                <Arg name="selectors" type="int"><Property name="jetty.ssl.selectors" deprecated="ssl.selectors" default="-1"/></Arg>
                <Arg name="factories">
                    <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
                        <!-- uncomment to support proxy protocol
                        <Item>
                          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ProxyConnectionFactory"/>
                        </Item>-->
                    </Array>
                </Arg>

                <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.ssl.host" deprecated="jetty.host" /></Set>
                <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.ssl.port" deprecated="ssl.port" default="8443" /></Set>

                <Set name="idleTimeout"><Property name="jetty.ssl.idleTimeout" deprecated="ssl.timeout" default="30000"/></Set>
                <Set name="soLingerTime"><Property name="jetty.ssl.soLingerTime" deprecated="ssl.soLingerTime" default="-1"/></Set>
                <Set name="acceptorPriorityDelta"><Property name="jetty.ssl.acceptorPriorityDelta" deprecated="ssl.acceptorPriorityDelta" default="0"/></Set>
                <Set name="acceptQueueSize"><Property name="jetty.ssl.acceptQueueSize" deprecated="ssl.acceptQueueSize" default="0"/></Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </Call>

    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- Create a TLS specific HttpConfiguration based on the        -->
    <!-- common HttpConfiguration defined in jetty.xml               -->
    <!-- Add a SecureRequestCustomizer to extract certificate and    -->
    <!-- session information                                         -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <New id="sslHttpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
        <Arg><Ref refid="httpConfig"/></Arg>
        <Call name="addCustomizer">
            <Arg>
                <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer">
                    <Arg type="boolean"><Property name="jetty.ssl.sniHostCheck" default="true"/></Arg>
                </New>
            </Arg>
        </Call>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

`jetty-https.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">

<!-- ============================================================= -->
<!-- Configure a HTTPS connector.                                  -->
<!-- This configuration must be used in conjunction with jetty.xml -->
<!-- and jetty-ssl.xml.                                            -->
<!-- ============================================================= -->
<Configure id="sslConnector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">

    <Call name="addIfAbsentConnectionFactory">
        <Arg>

            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory">
                <Arg name="next">http/1.1</Arg>
                <Arg name="sslContextFactory"><Ref refid="sslContextFactory"/></Arg>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </Call>

    <Call name="addConnectionFactory">
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
                <Arg name="config"><Ref refid="sslHttpConfig" /></Arg>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </Call>
</Configure>
```

`jetty-ssl-context.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">

<!-- ============================================================= -->
<!-- SSL ContextFactory configuration                              -->
<!-- ============================================================= -->
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
    <New id="sslContextFactory" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
        <Set name="KeyStorePath"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/src/main/resources/keystore</Set>
        <Set name="KeyStorePassword">password</Set>
        <Set name="KeyManagerPassword">password</Set>
        <Set name="TrustStorePath"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/src/main/resources/keystore</Set>
        <Set name="TrustStorePassword">password</Set>

        <Set name="IncludeCipherSuites">
        <Array type="String">
            <Item>TLS_DHE_RSA.*</Item>
            <Item>TLS_ECDHE.*</Item>
        </Array>
    </Set>

    <Set name="ExcludeCipherSuites">
        <Array type="String">
            <Item>.*NULL.*</Item>
            <Item>.*RC4.*</Item>
            <Item>.*MD5.*</Item>
            <Item>.*DES.*</Item>
            <Item>.*DSS.*</Item>
        </Array>
    </Set>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

Comment: What client are you using?

Comment: Same exception in Chrome as well as Firefox. I think it is related to the certificate, but I'm not even sure what I'm looking for. So many contradictory explanations and examples out there for Jetty.

Comment: The `<Set name="IncludeCipherSuites">` does not override exclude.  Your algorithm, cipher, and protocol excludes are still present in the Jetty `SslContextFactory` and Java security banned list.

Comment: Yeah. You should probably just copy exactly what is configured in the documentation link that you provided.

Comment: If you enable DEBUG level logging for `org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl` and `org.eclipse.jetty.server`, then the Jetty startup will report the list of selected ciphers and protocols per your configuration on the server side.

Comment: Yeah, still same issue. I updated the configuration.

Answer (score 3):

change this:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>9.3.6.v20151106</version>
<configuration>                       
    <jettyXml>src/main/resources/jetty.xml,src/main/resources/jetty-
        ssl.xml,src/main/resources/jetty-https.xml,src/main/resources/jetty-ssl-context.xml</jettyXml>
</configuration>
```

to this:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>9.3.6.v20151106</version>
<configuration>                       
    <jettyXml>src/main/resources/jetty.xml,src/main/resources/jetty-
        ssl.xml,src/main/resources/jetty-ssl-context.xml,src/main/resources/jetty-https.xml</jettyXml>
</configuration>
```

(Reverse the order of jetty-https.xml and jetty-ssl-context.xml).

You are creating ssl-connector in jetty-https with a default SslContextFactory (`<Ref refid="sslContextFactory"/>` is null), then go on creating a new SslContextFactory that you are configuring, but it is not used anywhere.